# (Approximation) Algorithms for Weight Distribution / Subspace Weights Problem in coding theory

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

The Weight Distribution / Subspace Weights Problem in coding theory is defined as this: 
Instance: A binary $m$ by$n$ matrix $H$ and an integer $k > 0$ 
Question: Is there a set of $k$ columns of $H$ that sum to the all-zero vector?

You might also say: 
Given a binary $m$ by$n$ matrix $H$ and an integer $k > 0$, is there a vector $\vec{x}$, s.t.
$$
A\vec{x} = \vec{0}
$$
where $\vec{x}$ has Hamming Weight k?

This Problem is proven to be NP-complete ([On the Inherent Intractability of Certain Codiig Problems](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1055873)). But is there any fast (polynomial) exact (for small inputs) or approximation algorithm to solve the problem? 
So far I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/421000/37212, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/150978/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

[Dumer, Micciancio et al](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu//%7Edaniele/papers/DMS.pdf) addressed this in 2007 in their paper entitled
*Hardness of Approximating the Minimum Distance of a Linear Code*.

From the Abstract:

We show that the minimum distance $d$ of a linear code is not approximable to within any constant factor in random polynomial time (RP), unless NP (nondeterministic polynomial time) equals RP. We also show that the minimum distance is not approximable to within an additive error that is linear in the block length $n$ of the code. Under the stronger assumption that NP is not contained in RQP (random quasi-polynomial time), we show that the minimum distance is not approximable to within the factor $2^{\log^{1-\epsilon} n}$, for any $\epsilon> 0.$

Our results hold for codes over any finite field, including binary codes. In the process we show that it is hard to find approximately nearest codewords even if the number of errors exceeds the unique decoding radius $d/2$ by only an arbitrarily small fraction.